# Option Chaining instead of if/else

Tags: kotlin

Is there a more succint way to write the following code using option chaining and/or the elvis operator?

```
email.addSubject(if (creator != null)  String.format( inviteDescription, creator) else String.format(inviteDescriptionNoCreator, group))
```

It feels like there should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the normal **IF** expression

```
val subject = if (creator != null) {
    inviteDescription.format(creator)
} else {
    inviteDescriptionNoCreator.format(group)
}
email.addSubject(subject)
```

The Elvis Operator

```
val subject = creator?.let {
    inviteDescription.format(it)
} ?: inviteDescriptionNoCreator.format(group)
email.addSubject(subject)
```

If the goal is to write the shortest code possible then you could go with a single line Elvis operator. But if the goal is a readable code, I would choose the simple **if** expression or a multi line Elvis operator. I would even go one step ahead and move it to a separate method. But whatever you choose, please don't write everything in a single long line, rather put it in separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

Just taking advantage of `?.` and `?:` gives us the following:

```
email.addSubject(creator?.let { String.format(inviteDescription, it) } ?: String.format(inviteDescriptionNoCreator, group))
```

Unfortunately, that's still quite long and is arguably not much easier to read. You could shave off a bit more by using the `String.format` extension function:

```
email.addSubject(creator?.let { inviteDescription.format(it) } ?: inviteDescriptionNoCreator.format(group))
```